# How to check 4 Textboxes for data in VB .Net with different possibilities

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement, textbox, conditional-statements

I just want to write the text in these textboxes to a notepad.

I have 4 Textboxes

> 1) Textbox1.Text
>
> 2) Textbox2.Text
>
> 3) Textbox3.Text
>
> 4) Textbox4.Text

I have compulsary data in Textbox1.Text and Textbox4.Text all the time

And I have 4 Options. like

> Option 1: If Textbox2 and Textbox3, both are **not empty**
>
> Option 2: If Textbox2 **is empty**, but Textbox3 is **not empty**
>
> Option 3: If Textbox2 is **not empty**, but Textbox3 **is empty**
>
> Option 4: If **both** Textbox2 and Textbox3 **are empty**

My Code is

```
Dim Tags As String
    If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Textbox2.Text)) Then
        If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Textbox3.Text)) Then
            Tags = String.Format("{0}: {1}, {2}, {3}{4}{4}", Textbox1.Text, Textbox2.Text, Textbox4.Text, Textbox3.Text, Environment.NewLine)
            objWriter2.WriteLine(Tags)
        ElseIf (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Textbox2.Text)) Then
            If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Textbox3.Text)) Then
                Tags = String.Format("{0}, {2}, {3}{4}{4}", Textbox1.Text, Textbox2.Text, Textbox4.Text, Textbox3.Text, Environment.NewLine)
                objWriter2.WriteLine(Tags)
            End If
        ElseIf (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Textbox2.Text)) Then
            If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Textbox3.Text)) Then
                Tags = String.Format("{0}: {1}, {2}{4}{4}", Textbox1, Textbox2.Text, Textbox4.Text, Textbox3.Text, Environment.NewLine)
                objWriter2.WriteLine(Tags)
            End If
        Else
            objWriter2.WriteLine(Textbox1.Text + ", " + Textbox4.Text)
        End If
    End If
```

As you can see there's some difference in my code where `Tags = String.Format()`, when i choose a different option.

Answer (score 1):

An idea is to load a boolean array with a True/False depending on whether each textbox has a value or not, then use these in your logic:

```
Dim boxData As Boolean() = {TextBox1.Text.Length > 0, TextBox2.Text.Length > 0, TextBox3.Text.Length > 0, TextBox4.Text.Length > 0}

    If Not boxData(0) OrElse Not boxData(3) Then
        Throw new Exception("Textbox1 and Textbox4 must contain some data")
    ElseIf boxData(1) AndAlso boxData(2) Then
        'option 1
    ElseIf boxData(2) Then
        'option 2
    ElseIf boxData(1) Then
        'option 3
    Else
        'option 4
    End If
```

Note that the array is zero based so `TextBox1` is `boxData(0)`, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't want to display any Message box... if there's data or not.... I juz want it to write to a text file according to the options I have provided in my question.

Comment: If they are compulsory and there is nothing in them, then you need to do something. What you do is up to you. You could throw an exception instead. I have changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Where should I write Objwriter.writeline() ??? after the End If ??? and what name should i put in the brackets ??? boxData ???

Comment: Nice solution, but I would say that I always use `TextBox.Text.Trim.Length` for non-password fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
'set variables equal to textbox values
Dim strText1 As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim strText2 As String = TextBox2.Text
Dim strText3 As String = TextBox3.Text
Dim strText4 As String = TextBox4.Text

'better option than If...Then because it doesn't go through all possibilities,
'only goes until it finds one that is valid for use
Select Case strText2
    Case Is <> Nothing And strText3 <> Nothing
         'option 1
    Case is = Nothing And strText3 <> Nothing
         'option 2
    Case Is <> Nothing And strText3 = Nothing
         'option 3
    Case Else
         'option 4
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is something easier you can do for this with much less code:

```
if textbox1.text.trim.length Or textbox2.text.trim.length Or textbox3.text.trim.length Or textbox4.text.trim.length < 1 Then
MessageBox.Show("Textbox1 and Textbox4 must contain some data")
```